# how to remove 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

how to resolve 'int' object is not callable

I am new over here

```
-68+(((68)**2-4(34)(-510))**0.5)/(2*34)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       -68+(((68)**2-4(34)(-510))**0.5)/(2*34)
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

there is no output only the error message written above. How to resolve this error message?

Comment: With `4(34)` you're trying to treat `4` as a callable object to make a call with `34` as the argument. If you mean to perform multiplication, you should use the `*` operator instead: `4 * 34`

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support multiplication through parentheses (like `(34)(-510)` and `4(34)`). Change this to `(34) * (-510)`. So, your full line would be:

```
>>> -68+(((68)**2-4*(34)*(-510))**0.5)/(2*34)
-64.0
```

When you say `4(34)`, you're actually telling the interpreter to call the function named `4` with the argument `34`. (This is the same syntax as saying `a(34)`, where a is a function.) The error is because `4` is not a function, so you can't call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't work in the python interpreter directly, you need to do something with your calcul, like putting it in a variable like this :

```py
a = -68+(((68)**2-4*(34)*(-510))**0.5)/(2*34)
```

or print it :

```py
print(-68+(((68)**2-4*(34)*(-510))**0.5)/(2*34))
```

Also you can't do maths with two values into parenthesis, you need to include a '*'.

Finally, doing `4(34)` is like you're calling a function named "4", with an argument (34).